# Setting element in nested list using arbitrary length index

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested

I have some lists and values nested inside each other with arbitrary depth.

```
nested = [
    3,
    [1, 4, 2],
    [3, [5], 6, 7, [5]],
    [3],
    [[1, 1],[2, 2]]
]
```

I am trying to set a value inside of this nested mess
using an arbitrarily long index.

Example index:

```
index = (2, 1)
```

So setting an item at the example index:

```
nested[2][1] = new_value
```

If we know the length of the index we can:

```
nested[index[0]][index[1]] = new_value
```

The problem is that the index is not a set length!

I figured out how to **get** a value for an arbitrary length index:

```
def nested_get(o, index):
    if not index:
        return o

    return nested_get(o[index[0]], index[1:])
```

I know numpy arrays can do this like: `np_array[index] = new_value`

How could I implement a function that does something like that but with pure python? Something like the `nested_get` but for setting a value.

Comment: Setting is the same as getting, you just need to pass an extra argument. When you get to the last index, do the assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something with a recursive function:

```
def nested_set(x, index, value):
    if isinstance(index, int):
        x[index] = value
        return
    elif len(index) == 1:
        x[index[0]] = value
        return
    nested_set(x[index[0]], index[1:], value)
```

It is likely that there's some better data structure to do what you want than lists.

Comment: @Hadus What might have confused you is that your getter uses an empty array as the base case, but you need to use `len == 1` as the base when setting, so you have the last list to assign to.

Comment: @user2653663 I am not even using lists but pytorch modules :) so it would require subclassing all the used modules to include better indexing but this is sufficient

Comment: @Barmar I didn't think of using the index **and** the one higher list to simply index into it. It just slipped my mind.